# How does the red rose scene impact Hester's decision to keep their relationship a secret in "The Scarlet Letter" by Nathaniel Hawthorne?

Tags: symbolism, theme, nathaniel-hawthorne, the-scarlet-letter

In Nathaniel Hawthorne's novel "The Scarlet Letter," the red rose serves as a symbol of their shared passion and love. [When Hester and Dimmesdale encounter the red rose in the forest](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/33/pg33-images.html#chap08), it reaffirms the intensity of their hidden feelings for each other. The vibrant red color of the rose reflects the intensity of their emotions, reminding them of the forbidden desire they share. It strengthens their bond and reminds them of the depth of their connection, despite the secret nature of their relationship.

How does the red rose scene impact Hester's decision to keep their relationship a secret?

Comment: Can you please post a link to the book's page where they encounter the red rose in the forest? It's free via Project Gutenberg and the one you posted via your question is tagged as dangerous by my spam etc. software.